# How to add a DropDownList programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I've got a masterpage on which a DropDownList should be displayed. Then I've got a class which should create a DropDownList. But since I've only got one page with a DDL I don't want to write inside the masterpage.aspx. So my question is if it is even possible to write all the code inside C# to create the DropDownList. Do I need someting like that?

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlChannel" runat="server">
```

or can I just do it like that:

```
Panel pnlChannel = new Panel();
```

But if I do it in the codebehind It won't display anything

This is my code so far:

```
 public Panel GetDropDownList()
{
    // Create drop down list and data source
    Panel pnlChannel = new Panel();
    DropDownList ddlChannel = new DropDownList();
    ListItem limDefault = new ListItem();
    SqlDataSource sdsChannel = new SqlDataSource();

    // Configure data source
    sdsChannel.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString;
    sdsChannel.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Kanal";
    sdsChannel.ID = "sdsChannel";

    // Configure drop down list
    ddlChannel.DataTextField = "Kanal";
    ddlChannel.DataValueField = "Kanal";
    ddlChannel.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    ddlChannel.DataSourceID = "sdsChannel";



    // Configure default list item
    limDefault.Selected = true;
    limDefault.Text = "Alle";
    limDefault.Value = "-1";

    // Add controls to static panel in footer
    ddlChannel.Items.Add(limDefault);
    pnlChannel.Controls.Add(ddlChannel);
    pnlChannel.Controls.Add(sdsChannel);

    return pnlChannel;
}
```

I don't really know what I have to do, to display it on the page.
If I debug it and execute the page, it calls the method but it still won't show up on the page

Comment: is it not displaying any of your control?

Comment: @HariPrasad It can't find .Controls. Can I even use it when I don't have a page? It doesn't display anything, expect the chart which I generate above , but I also don't think that it's behind the chart.

Comment: maybe settings elements width and height will work?

Comment: I've made a complete website in .net and everything was generated by .net. The only problem was the page load() function. If you put this request after the page load() it won't show it on your webpage, because there is no callback. 
Try to use this function like Form1.Controls.add(GetDropDownList()). 

You can use .controls when it isn't a webpage as long as you add using System.Web.UI.WebControls

Answer (score 2):

**Html Markup:**

Add a panel control on your .aspx page

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

**Code-behind:** on pageload

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource = sdsChannel;
ddl.DataTextField = "Kanal";
ddl.DataValueField = "Kanal";
ddl.DataBind();
Panel1.Controls.Add(ddl);
```

---

**Html Markup :**

Added panel control on master page under form tag

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlMasterPage" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

**Method 1 :** On masterpage on_load

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource = sdsChannel;
ddl.DataTextField = "Kanal";
ddl.DataValueField = "Kanal";
ddl.DataBind();
pnlMasterPage.Controls.Add(ddl);
```

**Method 2 :**
 If you want to bind from child page then, on child page on_load

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource = sdsChannel;
ddl.DataTextField = "Kanal";
ddl.DataValueField = "Kanal";
ddl.DataBind();
Panel pnl = this.Master.FindControl("pnlMasterPage") as Panel;
pnl.Controls.Add(ddl);
```

Comment: For sure I could add it to the .aspx page, but there isn't one for this method, there is only one masterpage for every site

Comment: @fusionchart_help: what exactly you want ??  Do you want to populate a dropdown which is placed in masterpage ? or do you want to populate a dropdownlist of childpage ?  your post is not much clear

Comment: I don't only want to populate, I also wan't to create the DropdownList. I thought i gonna do it like that: I make one masterpage and put it on the masterpage and whenever the page with the DropDownList is called it should set its visibility to true.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is based on WinForms with C#, still it may be relevant.

As in your code, this could work:

```
Panel pnlChannel = GetDropDownList(); //returns a configured panel with controls.
pnlChannel.Location = new Point(56,72); //Should not be required
pnlChannel.Size = new Size(264, 152); //Should not be required
pnlChannel.Visible=true; //(Or sometimes Show(), depending).
```

Do you know if the panel has to be added somewhere? Sorry, my exp is based on WinForms, it's not required.

Comment: I still can't see anything, but .Location and .Size don't work. Do you know if I even need to retun the pnlChannel or do I have to do it in an other way?